# If statement has trouble with text();

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

```
who = $(".tekst").text();

if (who=="XxX") {
    $("#discu").css("display", "none");
}

alert(who);
```

So my `.tekst` is:
`<a class="tekst" href="#">XxX</a>` and when I call a `text()` function, I get printed out `XxX` just like I want (I can see that in `alert();` box). The problem is, that my `if` statement doesn't work. It's output is just `false`. Why?

Comment: It's possible there are many .tekst links so the `.text()` function returns all their text combined. Use `$(".tekst:eq(0)").text()`

Comment: Your code is working fine. I have tried it with SO snippet and execute it perfecly.

Comment: your code is working in my cause. make sure that element with ID `#discu` exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the trailing and leading whitespace by using **[`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)** or **[`jQuery.trim()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/)** method.

```
who = $(".tekst").text().trim();

if (who=="XxX") {
    $("#discu").css("display", "none");
}

alert(who);
```

Comment: @Kajcioch There is chance for space in your mark up `<a class="tekst" href="#">   XxX    </a>` .   I can't see any other thing wrong with your code....

Comment: it's actualy true. Thanks a lot. I'll mark it as answer :)

Comment: @Kajcioch :  glad to help :)